# I need assistance with xcode buttons

Tags: xcode

So I'm trying to make an event happen with buttons in xcode, and it's working fine, and executing the way I want it to, but now I want a different section of code to run if the button is not being pushed. I don't know how to test for if a button is NOT being pushed. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While a NSButton is pressed its state is non-zero.

```
if (myButton.state) {
    // My button is pushed!
}
```

Comment: I'm writing   if (myButton.state != 0) { //make image go up }   but this isn't working

Comment: That will tell you when it's pushed; the test for when it's not pushed would be… "if (myButton.state == 0)".

Comment: It's Still not working, it's either moving it up until it ends the game or not moving at all

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that can help you. Define a `var` ,`notPushed` whose value can be checked to see if button is called or not.

```
    var notPushed:Bool=true

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(sender:UIButton)
    {
      //....
      notPushed=false
    }
```

To check wether the button is pressed :

```
    if notPushed==true{
      //...
    } else {
      //...
    }
```

Link your button to the `buttonPressed`.

Comment: I haven't had a chance to try it yet. Thank you though!

Comment: I didn't see any code to set notPushed when the button is released.